# Remove Password Protection .htaccess (Nginx)

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, passwords

I'm trying to take my site live by removing the htpasswd protection
i'm not sure if this is related to my other predicament but hopefully not.
i've tried deleted and commenting out the language inside /sites-available/default that references my htpasswd.txt file but I can't get rid of the password protection this is basically how its setup: kbeezie.com/…

There's a million articles that explain how to remove htaccess password protection but most of them are for apache and suggest creating an .htaccess file and writing: Satisfy Any and Allow All etc but none of that works for me.
of course -_-;;.

I've tried deleteing the .htpasswd file and removing the code that references it (also deleted the code) and none of that worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion to anyone with a problem such as this involving unknowns that cannot be dealt with after much effort (days of effort): Go to your Server (in my case digital ocean) and create a new (take a snapshot of your server to apply to your new IP) IP / droplet for your site. Uninstall your server engine (Nginx or Apache) and reinstall on the new server / IP. It's a little annoying but at least you wont be stuck like I was for days.